# How to insulate a crawl space without an access point

Tags: insulation, crawlspace

I have a cottage that has recently been completely renovated but later learnt that the floor was not insulated because there isn't an access panel.  The cottage doesn't have a crawl space the area below the floor to ground is only 18-24 inches.  Is there a way to have closed cell spay foam applied from the exterior of the home?

Comment: Have you considered cutting an access hatch through the interior floor in an inconspicuous place? 18"-24" is big enough for a technician to apply insulation from below...

Comment: What size is the cottage? Are the floors cold in the winter? Is it possible that the foundation itself was insulated? If the crawl space is pretty well sealed, any warmth that escapes through the floor should be reasonably well contained by a well sealed foundation. 18-24" of dead air space does make for a pretty good insulation barrier in-and-of-itself.

Comment: Consider making @JimmyFix-it's access hatch a permanently available trap door. If there is any plumbing or wiring in the crawl space, you'll need to get down there eventually to repair or upgrade something.